# Moving to 64 bit SAS

Tags: sas

I have few hundreds of SAS programs running every day on schedule.

If I upgrade the SAS to 64 bit, how can I prevent the error due to migration (maybe syntax/ procedure requirement change from 32 bit to 64 bit)?

Comment: Are you changing from 32 to 64 bit on the same version, ie 9.3 to 9.3?

Comment: I don't know.. It only shows SAS EG 6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major differences between 32 and 64 bit SAS from a usability perspective:

- Importing Excel (and Access) files.  If you're on Windows, your SAS bitness needs to match the bitness of Microsoft Office to use `DBMS=EXCEL` or `libname excel`.  See [this paper](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/02/11/export-excel-methods/) for some additional details.  There are some workarounds, including PC Files Server or using `DBMS=XLSX`, depending on your version and OS.
- Format catalogs.  Your format catalogs are not compatible between 32 and 64 bit SAS, just like they're not compatible between Unix and Windows.  In my opinion, your best bet is to use `CNTLOUT` option of `proc format` to export them to a dataset and then `CNTLIN` option to import them in 64 bit.  If you have mixed versions in your environment (some people with 32, some with 64), you'll want to either maintain two catalogs or have everyone interact with the `CNTLOUT` exported datasets only. This also applies to stored/compiled macro catalogs as well.
- Dataset version.  32 and 64 bit SAS can read each others' datasets, but at the expense of some slower access times; in my experience it's not *too* bad, but if you have large datasets you will want to convert them using `proc migrate` or simply read them in and re-write them out in 64 bit once.

Chris Hemedinger covers the same three issues in his blog post [on The SAS Dummy](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/05/01/64-bit-gotchas/) with some additional details.

In general, syntax for data step and procedure are no different between the two versions, although certainly with more memory some techniques that are impractical in 32 bit become available in 64 bit (large hash tables, some PROCs which will work very efficiently with large amounts of RAM).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any syntax differences between 32 and 64 bit. You should convert the data, check out `proc migrate`